# Incorrect syntax near ')'. in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have create Sp that return record on condition. it is work on my local server but when i deploy on another server im getting error

> 153|error|500|Incorrect syntax near '*'. Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'. Unexpected error occured while retrieving
>   data.Please try again later|

This is my query:-

```
     DECLARE @MemberID int  
    DECLARE @FolderID INT -- 1 = Inbox, 2 = Draft, 3 = Sent Items, 4 = Deleted Items, 5 = Templates etc    
     DECLARE @Email varchar(50)  
    DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PageSize INT  
    DECLARE @PageNumber INT  
    DECLARE @EnvelopeCurrentStatus varchar(5)  
    DECLARE @Subject varchar(50)   
    DECLARE @DateFrom VARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @DateTo VARCHAR(15) 




    SET @MemberID =35185  
    SET @FolderID =1 -- 1 = Inbox, 2 = Draft, 3 = Sent Items, 4 = Deleted Items, 5 = Templates etc    
    SET @Email ='sd' 
    SET @OrderBy = 'ti.ID DESC'  
    SET @PageSize =10  
    SET @PageNumber =1  
    SET @EnvelopeCurrentStatus  = '' 
    SET @Subject  = ''  
    SET @DateFrom  = '1/1/1990'   
    SET @DateTo  = '1/1/2990'
--,@DocGuid uniqueidentifier='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 '

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX)  
    DECLARE @SQL3 varchar(Max)  
    DECLARE @Select varchar(50)  
    DECLARE @Expr varchar(max)  
    SET @SQL = ''  
    SET @OrderBy = ''  

    SET @Expr = ''  
    IF ((@DateFrom <> '' AND @DateFrom IS NOT NULL) AND (@DateTo <> '' AND @DateTo IS NOT NULL ) )  
           SET @Expr = @Expr + ' AND ti.CreatedOn BETWEEN ''' + @DateFrom + ''' AND ''' + @DateTo+''''

    IF @Subject <> '' AND @Subject IS NOT NULL 
     begin  
      BEGIN TRY
      DECLARE @nPortalUID AS uniqueidentifier
      SET @nPortalUID = CAST(@Subject AS uniqueidentifier)
      SET @Expr = @Expr + ' AND  ti.TemplateID= '''+@Subject+' '''
      end try

      BEGIN catch
      SET @Expr = @Expr + ' and ti.Subject LIKE ''%'+@Subject+'%'' '
      end catch
     end     




    IF @EnvelopeCurrentStatus <> '' AND @EnvelopeCurrentStatus IS NOT NULL  
            SET @Expr = @Expr + ' AND ti.EnvelopeCurrentStatus = ''' + cast( @EnvelopeCurrentStatus AS varchar(5))+ ''''

    IF @OrderBy ='' AND @OrderBy IS NOT NULL   
            SET @OrderBy = 'ti.ID DESC'
    ELSE   
            SET @OrderBy = @OrderBy  

    DECLARE @IsShare BIT
    DECLARE @ParentID INT
    SELECT @IsShare = m.MUIsShare, @ParentID = m.createdby FROM tblcontact m WHERE m.ID = @MemberID

    DECLARE @MemberParentID VARCHAR(MAX)

    IF @IsShare = 1 
    BEGIN
    SET @MemberParentID = cast(@MemberID AS varchar(5))
        --SET @MemberParentID = cast(@MemberID AS varchar(5))+ ', ' + cast(@ParentID AS varchar(5))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @MemberParentID = cast(@MemberID AS varchar(5))
    END

    SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT * INTO #TMP FROM (  
                    SELECT * FROM (  
                        SELECT (  
                            SELECT Count(*) FROM TemplateInfo ti  WHERE (ti.FolderID = '+ cast( @FolderID AS varchar(5) )+ ') AND (ti.MemberID IN( '+ @MemberParentID + '))  AND (ti.EnvelopeStatus = 2) '  

    SET @SQL2 = ' OR  (ti.ID IN (SELECT TempleteInfoID  FROM  Recipients AS r  WHERE (Email = '''+ @Email+''')  AND (FolderID = '+ cast( @FolderID AS varchar(5))+') ) ) ) AS TotalRecord  
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+ @OrderBy + ') AS ROWID , ti.ID  , ti.TemplateID  , ti.EnvelopeStatus  , ti.EnvelopeCurrentStatus  , ti.Subject  , ti.CreatedOn AS SentDate  
                , ti.CreatedOn  , ti.ModifiedOn  , m.FirstName + '' '' + m.LastName AS Sender  , m.Email AS SenderEmail  
                FROM TemplateInfo ti  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcontact AS m ON ti.MemberID = m.ID  
                WHERE (ti.FolderID = '+ cast( @FolderID AS varchar(5))+ ') AND (ti.MemberID IN( '+ @MemberParentID + '))  AND (ti.EnvelopeStatus = 2) '  

    SET @SQL3 = ' OR (ti.ID IN ( SELECT TempleteInfoID   FROM  Recipients AS r  WHERE (Email = '''+ @Email+''')  AND (FolderID = '+ cast( @FolderID AS varchar(5)) + ') ) ) ) AS Template  
                    WHERE ROWID BETWEEN  '+ CAST( (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)) +' AND '+CAST (@PageNumber*@PageSize AS  VARCHAR(5)) + ' ) AS TmpTable  

                SELECT * FROM #TMP  

                SELECT r.ID  , r.Guid  , r.Name  , r.Email  , r.RecipientOrder  , r.Status  , r.ModifiedOn  , r.TempleteInfoID  
                , CASE WHEN r.Status = 0 THEN ''Waiting to Sign''  WHEN r.Status = 1 THEN ''Completed''  WHEN r.Status = 2 THEN ''Declined'' END AS StatusText  
                FROM Recipients r WHERE r.IsActive <> 0 and r.TempleteInfoID IN (SELECT ID FROM  #TMP)  

                SELECT * FROM UsedCustomFields ucf WHERE ucf.TemplateInfoID IN (SELECT ID FROM  #TMP)  

                DROP TABLE #TMP '  

    SET @SQL = @SQL1 + @Expr + @SQL2 +@Expr + @SQL3  
    select @SQL
    --PRINT (@SQL)  
    EXEC (@SQL);  

    IF @@Error <> 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Unexpected error occured while retrieving data.Please try again later',16 , 1)
    END
```

Comment: Is the error coming from the actual stored procedure code (I assume upon creation of the stored procedure) or from the highly un-debuggable dynamically built string that's executed as SQL code at some later time?  (Which is really bad practice.)

Comment: how can i remove this error..please help..

Comment: First you need to identify where the error _is_.  This code is dynamically building other code.  That's a very bad thing.  As you're discovering, it makes debugging very difficult.  By dynamically building code at runtime you effectively get rid of any design-time, compile-time, deploy-time checking for errors and save all of your errors for the worst possible time... run-time.  The first thing you need to determine is if the syntax error is in the stored procedure code, or in that dynamic string of code.  If the latter, you need to get the string's run-time value and examine _that_ instead.

Comment: To see if the problem occurs when executing your dynamic script, uncomment the `PRINT` statement and run this script in Management Studio. You should be able to see the dynamic script in the *Messages* tab as printed by your `PRINT` statement (which happens before the dynamic script is executed). Copy the printed script in a new query window and debug it there. (It may be easier to spot the problem if you format it properly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is the data in production table contains quotes('). Since you are using dynamic sql, if the data itself contains a quote, it takes as the termination of the query string and thus query fails

Comment: FWIW sp_executesql allows dynamic SQL with parameters.